# Is "ROM" the same as internal flash memory?

Tags: storage, internal-storage, ram

I saw the Nexus S storage specs are

```
512MB RAM + 16GB iNAND flash memory
```

and for the HTC Incredible S:

```
768 MB RAM and 1.5 GB ROM and microSD slot up to 32GB (8GB card included)
```

Is the Incredible's ROM the same thing as the Nexus's iNAND flash memory?

Comment: Upvoted for the good edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can see here that the HTC's ROM is referred to as "internal storage" (although it says 1.1 GB): http://www.htc.com/www/product/incredibles/specification.html.

Comment: Are you sure Nexus-S has SD card slot? I cannot find the spec for that. Also, will Nexus-S flash memory, has better read/write performance compared to HTC's microSD card?

Comment: Whoa.  I swear the specs I linked said it had an SD card slot before ... maybe it was location-specific or something, I've been messing around with proxies.  As for performance, the iNAND is around 6 MB/s write and the SD card is probably a class-4 (4 MB/s).